# Terminal application location in filesystem

Tags: debian, gnome

I'm using gnome 3 on debian.  I want to create a launcher on the desktop for terminal.  Where is terminal in the file system?

Comment: this is not a programming question, and is easily googleable

Comment: Yeah, tell me the exact google search to use to find this?  I gave up after 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the output from running `which terminal`
failing that post on serverfault.com

Comment: which terminal didnt output anything, posted over there, thanks.  didnt know server questions went there.

Comment: they answered over there, gnome-terminal, /usr/bin/gnome-terminal